# GEE, scatter plot between two raster with different numbers of pixels

Tags: google-earth-engine, ndvi, land-surface-temperature, scatterplot

Im trying to figure out how to exclude pixels from one raster so it has the same amount of pixels from the other one. I need to make a scatter plot between the two. I've tried pairing the two bands into one image, already defined a crs for both of them and put them at the same scale; none of it worked.

Here is my code:

https://code.earthengine.google.com/?scriptPath=users%2Fykgelli%2FTCC_Modis%3ALandSurfaceTemperature%2FTemporalSeries%20(copy)

Error generating chart: xLabels must be the same length as the 1-D vectors from the array. xLabels is of length 9994848 and the vectors are of length 9999907.

Comment: Could you please add the code to the question body? Link returns `Repository users/ykgelli/TCC_Modis does not exist.` error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the underlying data is still at different spatial extents. Here's what you could try:

- If these rasters are your own data, I'd recommend using GDALWARP to reproject to common resolution, extents, and projection prior to uploading to GEE.
- If they are GEE rasters, then clipping both of them with the same geometry should get the extents to match.

If that doesn't work, it's likely that your rasters have different origins and you'll need to resample one (or both) to make each pixel exactly match the other.

Comment: Yes! They are GEE raster. MODIS images pre_processed, so some of the pixels were ignored because of insuficient data. I masked both of them so they had the same pixels and it worked out! Thanks!!